# Microsoft Robotics Studio and absolute path problems

Tags: robotics-studio

I have just installed Microsoft Robotics Studio 2008 R2, and I must admit that I'm shocked to discover how paths are handled.

First of the studio wants to install itself into my personal profile (this is on Vista):

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\Microsoft Robotics Dev Studio 2008 R2
```

I assume this is because during development I have to write files to the robotics studio folder making `C:\Program Files` a no go.

Then when I create a new robotics project a lot of absolute paths pointing to the robotics studio is added to the project. If I check my project into source control and another developer checks it out onto his machine the absolute paths will not resolve and the project will not compile.

Also, since all services are collected into a single folder in the robotics studio folder developing multiple independent services on a single computer appears to be at least confusing.

Do you have any good strategies for handling this mess?

Comment: I find it odd that some people thinks this belong to SuperUsers.com. This question is very much a developer question about a specific development environment (actually Visual Studio 2008) and problems in this environment caused by projects created by a Microsoft tool.

Comment: +1. Couldn't agree more. If I would have any problems with my development IDE, I would ask the question on SO, not on SU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now figured out a way to change a Microsoft Robotics DSS Service visual studio project into something that you can compile and run in you own source tree independent of the installation path of the robotics studio. Here is a description of what you need to do to modify the project:

1. Add the robotics studio bin path to you **PATH** environment variable to be able to execute `dssproxy.exe` without supplying a full path. I have installed robotics studio into the program files folder to avoid accidentially writing files to the robotics studio folders.
2. Open the **Properties** page for the project and select the **Build** tab. In the **Output** section change the **Output path** to **`Debug\bin`**. For .NET projects it is customary to compile into folders `bin\Debug` and `bin\Release` but the robotics hosting service *expects* to live in a folder named `bin` and will store data in the folder above the `bin` folder.
3. Go to the **Signing** tab and select a new key in the **Choose a strong name key file** box. You can either generate your own key at that point or use the `sn.exe` utility to generate a new key. Or if you have your own policy for creating keys follow that. The `sn.exe` utility can be found in the `tools` folder of robotics studio.
4. In the **Build Events** tab edit **Post-build event command line**:

   `dssproxy.exe /dll:"$(TargetPath)" /proxyprojectpath:"$(ProjectDir)Proxy" /keyfile:"$(SolutionDir)Key.snk" $(ProxyDelaySign) $(CompactFrameworkProxyGen) /binpath:"." @(ReferencePath->'/referencepath:"%(RootDir)%(Directory) "', ' ')`

   Pay attention to the argument to **`/keyfile`**. Enter an expression that locates the strong name key file created in the previous step.
5. Copy the files **`DssHost.exe`** and **`DssHost.exe.config`** (or `DssHost32.exe` and `DssHost32.exe.config` for the 32 bit hosting service) from the robotics studio bin folder into the project folder and add these files to the project. Set the **Build Action** to **Content** and **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy if newer**. Do the same for the **manifest file** for your service. Actually, the manifest file doesn't have to be in the same folder as the service, but copying it to the output folder enables you to do XCOPY deployment.
6. In the **Debug** tab change the **Start external program** to the **`DssHost.exe`** in the output folder of your project. You will have to build the project once to copy the file to the output folder. Clear the **Working directory**. Set the **Command line arguments** to

   `/p:50000 /t:50001 /m:DSSService1.manifest.xml`

   Change the manifest file name to the proper name in your project. You can modify the port numbers used either here or in the `DssHost.exe.config` file. If you are running in a protected Windows environment (UAC) you will have to use the **`httpreserve`** command to give yourself access to a particular port. You have to run this command as administrator.

   Debug settings are not stored in the project file and each developer will have to create personal settings.

You should also update the **Release** configuration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was only interested in the CCR of MS Robotics, I just add these assemblies as a reference to any project I use it with and just be done with it.

This works without any problems. So if you are also only interested in the CCR and DSS part of the studio then this could be your solution

Reinier

Answer (score 0):

we see this problem a lot. The absolute easiest solution is to specify the install directory when installing robotics studio to be "C:\program files\microsoft robotics studio". That way moving code between machines, checking out of source control, etc becomes a lot less problematic.

The other option is to use dssprojectmigration, which is included with RDS. Just run dssprojectmigration against your project directory, and it will correct all the hardcoded paths.